# How can Faker PHP call a method without parentheses

Tags: php, laravel

I was tinkering with Laravel's factory and realised FakerPHP can call formatters without parenthesis. Calling `fake()->lasName()` and `fake()->lastName` have the same effect.

I took a look at the repo on github, especially the `Faker\Generator` class, which is what you get when you call `fake()`, however I couldn't grasp how this works.

It seems that it resolves the property to one of its formatters, but I would like to know how exactly this is possible. Is it a PHP feature? Or did I miss something in FakerPHP's implementation?

Comment: Magic getters/setters, presumably - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members

Comment: Yes magic getters it seems: https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/blob/master/src/Faker/Generator.php#L274

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code, that way you could have found out yourself.